# conditional string splitting in R (using tidyr)

Tags: regex, r, tidyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
X <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,4), 
                variable = c("cost", "cost", "reed_cost", "reed_cost"))
```

I'd like to split the variable column into two; one column to indicate if the variable is a 'cost' and another column to indicate whether or not the variable is "reed". I cannot seem to figure out the right regex for the split (e.g. using tidyr)

If my data were something nicer, say:

```
Y <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,4), 
                variable = c("adjusted_cost", "adjusted_cost", "reed_cost", "reed_cost"))
```

Then this is trivial with tidyr:

```
separate(Y, variable, c("Type", "Model"), "_")
```

and bingo. Instead, it looks like I need some kind of conditional statement to split on "_" if it is present, and otherwise split on the start of the pattern ("^").

I tried:

```
separate(X, variable, c("Policy-cost", "Reed"), "(?(_)_|^)", perl=TRUE)
```

but no luck.  I realize I cannot even split to an empty string successfully:

```
separate(X, variable, c("Policy-cost", "Reed"), "^", perl=TRUE)
```

how should I do this?

**Edit** *Note* that this is a minimal example of a larger problem, in which there are many possible variables (not just `cost` and `reed_cost`) so I do not want to string match each one.

I am looking for a solution that splits arbitrary variables by the `_` pattern if present and otherwise splits them into a blank string and the original label.

I also realize I could just grep for the presence of `_` and then construct the columns manually.  That's fine if rather less elegant; it seems there should be a way to split on a string using a conditional that can return an empty string...

Comment: perhaps `tidyr::extract` would be better suited than `tidyr::separate`, though it appears it does not support perl=TRUE at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you may or may not have a separator and that cost and reed aren't necessarily mutually exclusive, why not search for the specific string instead of the separator?

Example:

```
library(stringr)
X <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,4), 
                variable = c("cost", "cost", "reed_cost", "reed_cost"))
X$cost <- str_detect(X$variable,"cost")
X$reed <- str_detect(X$variable,"reed")
```

Comment: Ah, this is the problem with posing minimal examples.  I should have mentioned that there are many other variables in the variable column, such as profit and reed_profit, tvalue and reed_tvalue, etc, so I really would prefer a scalable solution that splits as I described...

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
X$variable <- ifelse(!grepl("_", X$variable), paste0("_", X$variable), as.character(X$variable))

 separate(X, variable, c("Policy-cost", "Reed"), "_")
 # value Policy-cost Reed
 #1     1             cost
 #2     2             cost
 #3     3        reed cost
 #4     4        reed cost
```

Or

```
X$variable <-  gsub("\\b(?=[A-Za-z]+\\b)", "_", X$variable, perl=T)
 X$variable
#[1] "_cost"     "_cost"     "reed_cost" "reed_cost"

 separate(X, variable, c("Policy-cost", "Reed"), "_")
```

#### Explanation

`\\b(?=[A-Za-z]+\\b)` : matches a word boundary `\\b` and looks ahead for characters followed by word boundary.  The third and fourth elements does not match, so it was not replaced.

Comment: I have struggled with the following, and can't offer it as an answer, but what is my mistake?  ifelse(grepl(df$variable, pattern = "(?=.*_.*)", perl = TRUE), strsplit(df$variable, "_", fixed = TRUE), df$variable)

Comment: @lawyeR. In the example, df$variable is factor, so, you need to change it to as.character(df$variable.  For, e.g. `ifelse(grepl(df$variable, pattern="(?=.*_.*)", perl=T), str_split(df$variable, "_"), as.character(df$variable))`,it gives an output, but the first two elements in the resulting list only have one element `cost`, it should have `""` and `cost`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with base R:

```
cbind(X["value"], 
      setNames(as.data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(as.character(X$variable), "_"), 
                                      function(x) 
                                        if (length(x) == 1) c("", x) 
                                        else x))), 
               c("Policy-cost", "Reed")))

#   value Policy-cost Reed
# 1     1             cost
# 2     2             cost
# 3     3        reed cost
# 4     4        reed cost
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer, but doesn't it seem like the conditional should be possible with regex instead of an R function?  It would be much more concise that way.